# Pass object from JSP to a action class in Struts 1.3

Tags: java, jsp, hyperlink, struts, javabeans

I want to pass an object from JSP to an action class. How to do it? I have no idea regarding it. Some of my sample codes are here:

```
<tr class="alt">
    <td><html:link href=""><bean:write name="EmpInfo" property="empId" /></html:link></td>
    <td><bean:write name="EmpInfo" property="empName" /></td>
    <td><bean:write name="EmpInfo" property="empAddress" /></td>
    <td><bean:write name="EmpInfo" property="empPhNumber" /></td>
    <td><bean:write name="EmpInfo" property="empEmailId" /></td>
    <td><bean:write name="EmpInfo" property="empLocName" /></td>
    <td><bean:write name="EmpInfo" property="empCountryName" /></td>
    <td><bean:write name="EmpInfo" property="empDob" /></td>
    <td><html:link href=""><bean:message key="view.single.emp.update"/></html:link></td>
</tr>
```

in the above code in the `<html:link href="">` tag i wanna pass the `empId` or the object `EmpInfo` to an action class. Here's `EmpInfo` is value object and it has all the getter and setters in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `html:param` tag, it could be used in the body of `html:link` tag

```
<html:link href=""><html:param name="empId"><bean:write name="EmpInfo" property="empId" /></html:param></html:link>
```

Comment: this above code is not working, though it is not showing any error but the table field is empty i.e not showing any values in it nor the hyper link. but an interesting thing is that when i viewed the source code in the generated html it's showing this :  `<td>
                    <a href="viewDetailInfo.do?empId=EMP_3"></a>
                </td>
                ` but i have used the bean message still it's not displaying

Comment: @sasuke You have asked how to pass object through the link, I'm not intended to write a working code here, because it's copied and pasted from your question and modified to reflect the details of this answer.

Comment: i have found the answer @roman c . thanks for your help , you did most of the job. i am uploading the correct ans.

Comment: Ok, good if it helped, if you find it useful, regardless what url you using to call the action, then you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The control flow of Struts is like this:

1. A HttpRequest apears
2. ActionServlet receives it, populates proper ActionForm, and pass the control to an Action
3. Action performs the logic, and forwards or redirects to an ActionForward

So if you forward to a JSP, then you won't pass the control to another action again directly, but the next action is invoked after a new request from user browser is sent.

So the only way to pass an object is to pass its properties as request parameters (GET or POST preferred).

By the way using Struts 1.2+ you are not forced to have just String fields in ActionForm. Have your object in action form referenced it with Java Beans convention:

```
class MyActionForm extends ActionForm {
    private MyBean myBean;

    public MyBean getMyBean() {
        if (myBean == null) {
            myBean = new MyBean();
        }
        return myBean;
    }
}
```

Now you can access its properties with *myBean.property1* in your JSP tags, and a request parameter with name myBean.property1 will be populated to the property.

Struts 1.2+ uses Apache Commons BeanUtils internally, so you can use its Converters for complex types.

Comment: Well i am extending ` MappingDispatchAction` and not `ActionForm`. and the method there is `public ActionForward viewDetailInfo(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception 
    {
        
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }` which is quite simple i just forwaded it to the next jsp and then used the bean object which i have declared in session attribute.

Comment: by the way would you please elaborately explain the last part starting from the coding .. i couldn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

Add your object to the session or request object by `setAttribute()` method. You can get it from an action class by `getAttribute()`.

Comment: i have used setAttribute() method i.e `request.setAttribute("EmpInfo", empInfoVO);` in action class and then i have passed it here in this jsp. and now i want to pass this object from this jsp to another action class. How can i do that?

Comment: Use session.setAttribute() method. Then you can get it any where from your application.

Comment: ok i got it , but is there no way to pass from this jsp to action class except making it in session attribute?? if any then please kindly share it, i would like to know that...

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct working code. thanx to @roman c for helping me out

```
 <td>
                <html:link href="viewDetailInfo.do">
                    <html:param name="empId">
                        <bean:write name="empList" property="empId" />
                    </html:param>
                        <bean:write name="empList" property="empId" />
                </html:link>
 </td>
```